# Sql difference between top two from each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data table in mysql database which has time series data

```
**Table Sensor Data**  
ID    uuid  server_time
1      a    2021-07-29 11:36:15
2      b    2021-07-29 11:36:15
3      a    2021-07-29 12:36:15
4      b    2021-07-29 11:39:15
5      a    2021-07-29 13:36:15
```

I want to find time difference in minutes between server_time of the two latest data for each uuid. So for a it would be between 2021-07-29 13:36:15, 2021-07-29 12:36:15 and for b it would be between 2021-07-29 11:39:15, 2021-07-29 11:36:15.
The query should be performant enough because there are over 2 million records in the table. I am open to adding indexes to increase performance.

Comment: What difference between 2021-07-29 13:36:15 and 2021-07-29 12:36:15?

Comment: Time difference in minutes

Comment: You should mentions this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select uuid,
       max(server_time) as latest_server_time,
       min(server_time) as penultimate_server_time,
       timestampdiff(second, min(server_time), max(server_time)) as diff_seconds
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by uuid order by server_time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2
group by uuid
having count(*) >= 2;
```

You might want an index on `(uuid, server_time desc)`.

Comment: Be aware that `row_number` is only available since MySQL 8.

Comment: Doesn't perform. I am not getting results even after 30 seconds. I have indexes on server_time and uuid.

Comment: @devJoshi . . . On 2 million rows, that seems surprising.  Are other processes perhaps locking the table?